# np.ceil in python doesn't work in for loop

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and I have a problem with the np.ceil function. So when I do `np.ceil(10/0.1)`, I get 100, which is what I expect. However when I do it in a for loop:

```
interval = np.arange(0.01,0.2,0.01)
for i in interval:
    print(np.ceil(10/i))
```

I obtain the right results for all values of i, except for i=0.1. For this I get 101 instead of 100. Can someone tell me why is this happening? Thank you!

Comment: Floating-point math is approximate.

Comment: But why is it working for all the others? And why when I use 0.1 it works but when i=0.1 it doesn't work? Thank you!

Comment: "But why is it working for all the others?" - total fluke.

Comment: Wait I am confused. What is the point of np.ceil then, if the result is wrong? And again, why does it work when I put the number directly, but it doesn't when I put it as a variable?

Comment: Because floating point math is approximate *and* .1 cannot be exactly represented as a floating point number. So in neither case are you actually dividing by .1, you're dividing instead by two *different* approximations of .1, one that is smidge less than .1 and one that's a smidge more.

Comment: So is there any way I go around this? Because I really need to do this in a for loop?

Comment: You can use `decimal.Decimal` for arbitary precision. This comes at a speed/memory cost though, and you'll have to implement your own `arange` function.

Comment: Also note, this has nothing to do with python/numpy per se, but is a fundamental issue with binary floating point numbers, which the vast majority of languages / computer architectures really.

Comment: The best way to avoid floating point issues is to avoid floating point arithmetic altogether and work with integers for as long as possible.

Comment: And of course, `decimal.Decimal` can't actually fix the problem; it just makes the problem cases line up better with the cases human intuition expects to be problematic. For example, `floor(1/Decimal(9)*Decimal(9)) == 0`.

Comment: @user2357112 would a CAS like `sympy` be able to "solve" the above correctly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Yeah, easily, but a CAS can't fix everything either. It can find exact solutions for a lot of cases, especially if the operations involved are simple enough, but eventually you'll run into limitations and either sympy will fail to simplify something, or you won't be able to express your operation in sympy at all.

Comment: Don't forget [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html). It will maintain exact results for rational numbers up until you actually need a floating point approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with being in a variable or not. The values are simply not the same:

```
In [9]: interval
Out[9]:
array([ 0.01,  0.02,  0.03,  0.04,  0.05,  0.06,  0.07,  0.08,  0.09,
        0.1 ,  0.11,  0.12,  0.13,  0.14,  0.15,  0.16,  0.17,  0.18,  0.19])

In [10]: x = interval[9]

In [11]: x
Out[11]: 0.099999999999999992

In [12]: i = 0.1

In [13]: x == i
Out[13]: False
```

Note, neither number is exactly `0.1` since that number cannot be represented exactly using binary floating point. Also note:

```
In [14]: type(x), type(i)
Out[14]: (numpy.float64, float)
```

Although, that isn't as relevant.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there any way I can go around this?

Comment: @BillKet get around what exactly?

Comment: To have the number I want there, which is 0.1 and not 0.099999999999999992.

Comment: @BillKet you can use `decimal.Decimal` objects rather than `float` or `numpy.float64` objects. They can represent decimal numbers exactly, but this will come at a speed/memory cost. You will likely have to implement your own `arange` function as well. Here is the doc: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html

Comment: @BillKet also note, as someone pointed out in the comments, `decimal.Decimal` will not solve all your issues, since you cannot have infinite precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can force another float representation by rounding it.

This should do the trick in your specific case.

```
interval = np.arange(0.01,0.2,0.01)
for i in interval:
    if i == 0.1:
        print('this will miss')
    if i == interval[9]:
        print('this will hit')
    j = round(i, 3)
    print(np.ceil(10/i), np.ceil(10/j))
```